# detect usernames and make that text linkable and clickable in string

Tags: java, android, string, hyperlink, textview

i want to detect username in string from arraylist(this is coming from response) and make it clickable and linkable username in string

ex: i have a string

`@abc @hello @ryan @rita`-->this is my string

i have a arraylist of username:`[ryan,abc]`

if i found ryan and abc in my string i want make it linkable
else i have to keep the rest  the string as such

please help out

following is my code:--

```
   if (model.getMentionedUsernames().size()>0) {
            SpannableString ss = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < model.getMentionedUsernames().size(); i++) {
                if (text.contains(model.getMentionedUsernames().get(i))) {
                     ss = new SpannableString((model.getMentionedUsernames().get(i)));
                    ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View textView) {
                            Toast.makeText(context,"skdv",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
                            super.updateDrawState(ds);
                            ds.setUnderlineText(false);
                        }
                    };
                    int startIndex = text.indexOf(model.getMentionedUsernames().get(i));
                    int endIndex = startIndex + model.getMentionedUsernames().get(i).length();

                //    while (match.find()) {
                        ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, startIndex, endIndex , Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                 //   }

                }
            }
            normalpost_text.setText(ss);
            normalpost_text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            normalpost_text.setHighlightColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

above code crashing--:

E/UncaughtException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (1 ... 5) ends beyond length 4

any help will be appreciated

thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like you are getting the span indexes from `text` but setting the span on `ss`. That doesn't seem right. Set a breakpoint to examine these variables. I think you'll be able to tell what the problem is..

Answer (score 0):

int endIndex = startIndex + model.getMentionedUsernames().get(i).length();

i think you need to change code like below

int endIndex = startIndex + model.getMentionedUsernames().get(i).length()**-1**;

Comment: E/UncaughtException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (97 ... 99) ends beyond length 3

Comment: it is crashing...